# TokuMX does not restart after an upgrade

Tags: tokumx

I was trying to use TokuMX, so I did:

```
sudo mongod --config /etc/tokumx.conf
```

and it just takes forever, and no response.

My TokuMX once worked fine. Everything broke when I upgraded MongoDB.

Any suggestions?

----------------------EDIT----------------------

Problem solved by re-installed TokuMX following 
https://github.com/Tokutek/mongo/wiki/Migrating-Single-Server

Thanks everyone!

Comment: How long have you let it sit? TokuMX sometimes takes upwards of an hour to start up for me; check your disk IO. It's probably hitting it pretty hard. Subsequent restarts should be relatively quick.

Comment: TokuMX is a fork of MongoDB that uses the same server binary name (`mongod`) but uses different data file formats and options. The server binaries are not interoperable. When you upgraded did you install a newer version of TokuMX or perhaps install standard MongoDB? What specific server versions did you upgrade from and to? I would check the log file (as specified in `/etc/tokumx.conf`) and see if there are any obvious errors there. You could also check your MongoDB server version with `mongod --version`; TokuMX will report something like `TokuMX mongod server...`.

Comment: Currently, `mongod -- version` gives: `db version v2.6.9`. I upgraded from a 2.4.x version (forgot what it was...)

Comment: @Chris Heald more than 1 day...

Comment: @Stennie I know that the storage files are not compatible. I used TokuMX previously, and I simply want to continue using it after upgrading MongoDB... The command `sudo mongod --config /etc/tokumx.conf` stuck there for 1 day, and no output. Anything I could check? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you're using the tokumx `mongod` rather than the MongoDB `mongod`. Use the full path to the tokumx executable.

Comment: @ChrisHeald Thanks! That may be the problem! But how can I check which `mongod` that I'm using, or how can I find the path to the tokumx executable...? Thanks!